# How do install Apache mods in Tomcat?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, tomcat

I have a web app which can run inside a servlet container (I use Tomcat). Now I want to use load balancing because I have 2 of these servers. But, if I want to use mod_proxy_balancer, do I need to be running an Apache Server instance too? Can you load mods in Tomcat or do you have to set an Apache Server (with mod_proxy, mod_proxy_balancer) + Apache Tomcat Connector + Tomcat to use the load balancing mod?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to run an instance of Apache; Apache modules run only in Apache.  But you want that, anyway - mod_proxy_balancer is only gonna help you if it gets to distribute requests before they hit Tomcat!